# Unable to call WebAPI method through AJAX, works if debugger used in AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to post data through AJAX, but not able to call web api method. If I written debugger in my jquery Ajax call and did Inspect then i'm able to call Web API method. How can I fix it, and also not getting any error even in console.
Please help me.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: userDetail,
  url: "http://localhost:12345/api/User/Register",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(result) {
    debugger;
    if (result == "Success") {
      alert('User Detail Saved Successfully.');
      window.location.href = "http://localhost:12345/Home/Index";
    }
    if (result == "Failed") {
      $("#ErrorMessage").show();
    } else {
      $("#ErrorMessage").show();
    }
  },
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with this `if(response.status === "success") { ... }
} else if(response.status === "error") {...}`
Also,If you need **async: false** in your ajax, you should use **success** instead of **.done**. Else you better to use **.done**.

Comment: I have tried but not working.

Comment: Is your port always the same?

Comment: Yes, port is same.